# How do I change this picture to one from my documents?

Tags: javascript

As you can see below its a working code but the problem is that I wont have internet when I present this code to my teacher. Therefore I need to use pictures already saved in my document. [The picture is called image2.jpg and I got two other pictures called image1.jpg and image3.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJRid.png)

```
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to change to the next light.</p>

<img id="starting_light" src="http://mars.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/mediawiki/sk/images/thumb/1/1f/Red_Light_Icon.svg/232px-Red_Light_Icon.svg.png">

<button type="button" onclick="nextLightClick()">Next Light</button>

<script>

var lights = new Array("http://mars.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/mediawiki/sk/images/thumb/1/1f/Red_Light_Icon.svg/232px-Red_Light_Icon.svg.png","https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/Yellow_Light_Icon.svg/232px-Yellow_Light_Icon.svg.png","https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4b/Green_Light_Icon.svg");



var index = 0;
var lightsLen = lights.length;

function nextLightClick() {
    index++;

    if (index == lightsLen) 
        index = 0;

    var image = document.getElementById('starting_light');
    image.src = lights[index];
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Can one of you experts change this code so that those 3 pictures from the internet are the ones from my document. I dont know how to make a path to the pictures in my documents. The html code and the picture are in the same folder but it still doesnt work.

Comment: Try: `file:///C:/Users/tom/Documents/image2.jpg` assuming you have a Windows PC.

Comment: nope still didn't work.

Comment: You changed the`tom` portion to whatever sign on you have, right? What error did you get from the console (F12)?

Comment: file:///C:/Users/tom/Documents/image2.jpg Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: Yes actually I am using my dads laptop let me change it and see if it works.

Comment: Where can I find the name of the sign in. Not sure how to find it.

Comment: Try @kloarubeek answer it's much more simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the html file is in the same local folder as the images and then try this (so without any folder):

```
var lights = new Array("image1.jpg","image2.jpg","image3.jpg");
```

The browser assumes it's in the same folder as your html file and they will be loaded. No need for the full path!

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would probably be to save those three pictures to your computer, then move them into a folder along side your html document.  I usually set my files up with a root folder to hold all project files, with my html/php/whatever documents in the root folder, and a subfolder called `Images`.

Put all of your images and support files in that folder, and reference them from inside Javascript as below:

```
var lights = new Array("\Images\232px-red_Light_Icon.svg.png", "\Images\232px-Yellow_Light_Icon.svg.png", etc);
```

Just to clarify, you've changed the original web path to a local path.  You don't have to include the full file path (e.g. `C:\Users\Username\Pictures\image.png`) because by default, your script is looking in the folder where the html document is located, plus whatever path you've specified.  If your html document is in `C:\Users\User\Documents\`, the local paths described in the array above would equal `C:\Users\Documents\Images\232px-red_Light_Icon.svg.png`.

You can equally specify a full path by typing out the full location (e.g. `C:\Users\Documents\Images\232px-red_Light_Icon.svg.png`) if you had files stored somewhere else on your computer that you wanted to use, but this is bad practice because if you move or rename that file, you may not release it is referenced in a script.  By using an Images folder in the same folder as your script, you can essentially copy that root folder and move it anywhere and it will still have all of its supporting files.

Hope this helps!